# Share business logic in asp.net (c#) and android (java)

Tags: java, android, asp.net

I'm working on a project that has a website (asp.net c#) and android app (java) that share some common functionality.  Currently when they need to use the same business logic the android makes a call to the website and gets the results.  We've had a request for the android to work "offline", so it would need to perform that business logic without hitting the website.  Are there any ways to do that?

The only thing we've thought of so far are using javascript, as a node.js server for asp.net to hit and rhinoscript to include in the java.  This will work, but I was hoping for a less complex (not having to run node.js and .net servers).

An example of the logic needed is passing in a couple of products and calculating discounts, taxes, etc to return the total price.  It's a bit more complex than that, but not too much.

Comment: Is the android app just a WebView? Your website implements MVC pattern?

Comment: 1. How frequently will your business logic change? 2. Is downloading the business logic *once* suitable for your client?

Comment: The android app is a full blown app (I'm not the developer writing it, but I've looked at the code... it's got it's own DAO, views, logic, etc, including bluetooth communication, etc).

Comment: The business logic won't change much or often, but it could.  How would I go about downloading it to the client?  The client will be online/connected most of the time/day... it's just when it gets out of range that it would need to use offline logic (but would probably end up using the offline logic always as it'd be faster).

Answer (score 0):

1. Encapsulate the common logic into configuration, say for example, `xml`.
2. Publish this `xml` as a http resource.
3. Leverage http caching with `expires` and `etag` headers.
4. Wire up your Android app to poll the said http resource at a predefined interval.
5. Incorporate a local override mechanism for emergency updates wherein a locally defined xml overrides the one received via http.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this.  What language would the logic be in?  Is this just taking the javascript idea and making a way to publish it to the app?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to build a custom CDN Javascript library that has all of your shared logic and is included in both projects.

The behaviour would be similar to sharing a JQuery CDN, and if the connection is there, persist the CDN source locally, and if the source is disconnected, use the local source.